# how to getRange of more than one cell in same row in a script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Im trying to make a script that sends email alert when specific fields reaches certain values. It works fine for one field, but how Do I do it so it sends alert when any of the fields in specific row range reaches that value.
Im using this code:

```
function CheckSales() {
  // Tikrinam laukelio value
  var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("reportai").getRange("A15"); 
  var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();
  // tikrinam value
  if (monthSales < 200){
    // pasiimam email adresa
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
  
    // Siuncima email.
    var message = 'Mazas likutis: ' + monthSales; // Second column
    var subject = 'Mazas Likutis';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

I tried using `.getRange("A15:E15")` but still it send alert only when A15 reaches value less than 200, its not reacting to B15, C15 ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the values in `A15:E15` with a loop. Try this:

```
function checkSales() {
  const monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('reportai!A15:E15');
  const emailAddress = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Sheet1!B2').getValue();
  const subject = 'Mazas Likutis';
  let message = 'Mazas likutis: ';
  const alerts = [];
  monthSalesRange.getValues().flat()
    .forEach(sales => {
      if (Number(sales) && sales < 200) {
        alerts.push(sales);
      }
    });
  if (alerts.length) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message + alerts.join(', '));
  }
}
```

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Now its sending me email with values if it goes below 200, but it also sends me emails with empty values on every edit even if values are above 200 (I have function trigger set to on edit). Im really new in Javascript, my main language is PHP

Comment: I guess I need something like if (alerts.length > 0) but this doesn't work. It still sends email with empty fields (like this Mazas likutis: , ) if values are above 200

Comment: To guard against blank values, add `sales && ` in the condition. Edited the answer accordingly.